# how to get array from and xml file in swift

Tags: arrays, xml, swift

I am new to swift but I have made an android app where a string array is selected from an xml file. This is a large xml file that contains a lot of string arrays and the app gets the relevant string array based on a user selection.

I am now trying to develop the same app for iOS using swift. I would like to use the same xml file but I can not see and easy way to get the correct array. For example, part of the xml looks like this

```
 <string-array name="OCR_Businessstudies_A_Topics">
    <item>1. Business objectives and strategic decisions</item>
    <item>2. External influences facing businesses</item>
    <item>3. Marketing and marketing strategies</item>
    <item>4. Operational strategy</item>
    <item>5. Human resources</item>
    <item>6. Accounting and financial considerations</item>
    <item>7. The global environment of business</item>
</string-array>

<string-array name="OCR_Businessstudies_AS_Topics">
    <item>1. Business objectives and strategic decisions</item>
    <item>2. External influences facing businesses</item>
    <item>3. Marketing and marketing strategies</item>
    <item>4. Operational strategy</item>
    <item>5. Human resources</item>
    <item>6. Accounting and financial considerations</item>
</string-array>
```

If I have the string "OCR_Businessstudies_A_Topics" how do i get the "OCR_Businessstudies_A_Topics" array from the xml file.

This is very straight forward in android and although I have used online tutorials for swift it seems like I have to parse the xml file but do not seem to be getting anywhere.

Is there a better approach than trying to parse the whole xml fie?

Thanks

Barry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Xml into Array (Swift)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782864/parse-xml-into-array-swift)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write your own XML parser, conforming to `NSXMLParser` or use a library like [`HTMLReader`](https://cocoapods.org/?q=htmlreader):

```
let fileURL = NSBundle.mainBundle().URLForResource("data", withExtension: "xml")!
let xmlData = NSData(contentsOfURL: fileURL)!
let topic = "OCR_Businessstudies_A_Topics"

let document = HTMLDocument(data: xmlData, contentTypeHeader: "text/xml")
for item in document.nodesMatchingSelector("string-array[name='\(topic)'] item") {
    print(item.textContent)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Wrote my own xml parser in the end. Seems thats the only way to do it on swift. Got it working now and selecting the information I need from the xml file. Used the following tutorial to help (https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=XP4KCgAAQBAJ&lpg=PA145&dq=initialise%20an%20nsxmlparser%20with%20data%20swift&pg=PA145#v=onepage&q=initialise%20an%20nsxmlparser%20with%20data%20swift&f=false)